# SwitchCompat missing thumb drawable on 4.3 and below

Tags: android, android-appcompat, switchcompat

I'm using the [SwitchCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html) library in my app but it seems to be missing the thumb image on certain devices. (4.2.2, 4.1, 4.3 are the devices i tested on.) Instead it just displays the track with nothing indicating whether the switch is on or off.

[image]

Comment: How did you attach `appcompat-v7` to your project?

Comment: I added it as a dependency in my build.gradle file.

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'`

Is that correct? or is there another appcompat support library i should be including?

Comment: No, that should be OK. I was concerned that perhaps you were using on Eclipse, and you only copied a JAR into `libs/` or something and therefore were missing resources.

Comment: I ran into this myself, and filed a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78262

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. I have confirmed it on my Nexus 7. and as znggo has pointed out, He did file a bug report [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78262).